# std::string / reference counting / const

Tags: c++, string

as far as I know std::string can be reference counted or not. I would say reference counted strings have a better performance?
So my question is, **is it a good coding style to make std::string const**? For example a local variable oder a function argument. I like it, because it is easier to read code if you know a variable is intended to be altered or not.

To my understanding the value of a const string is copied if the variable is copied. Or am I wrong? I would say the reference counter can't be changed because it is const?

Comment: "I would say reference counted strings have a better performance?" - it entirely depends what you're doing with them. Note that, since C++11 they can't legitimately be reference counted, although some implementations still are.

Comment: "I would say the reference counter can be changed because it is const?" - assuming you meant "can't", that would rather defeat the point of reference counting. Presumably, it would be mutable even in a `const` string (which is reasonable, since it's not part of the visible state); but you'd have to consult a specific implementation to see what actually happens.

Comment: Const-correctness is always a good thing, until it's not.

Comment: Passing strings to functions as const reference will save a copy. By const value will not.

Comment: @Mike Seymour: Yes, I meant "can't".

Comment: @Neil Kirk: Yes, I forgot to say const reference (as function argument).

Comment: `as far as I know std::string can be reference counted or not` **std::string cannot be reference counted in C++11**. For instance, must have a `iterator begin() noexcept;` member, which means it cannot reallocate storage (and neither throw exceptions or return an invalid iterator), which means it can't be refcounted / copy on write. Also it can't invalidate its own storage when calling `begin`, as per §21.4.1.6 N3337. See also http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2534.html

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the latest std::string implementations are using Small String Optimization (SSO) instead of reference counting (because some performance caveats on multicore systems, due to needed locking). SSO consists of having an automatic fixed-sized array for small strings (for, say, 8 characters or so); so, if your string is small, there will not be need to allocate, deallocate memory on the heap.

The problem with SSO is that the performance of moving (using move semantics) a string to other one is not better than copying it if the string is small (because the whole fixed-size array must be copied).

So, use const references or rvalue references when possible and avoid using pass-by-value.

Comment: But the "whole fixed-size array" is small so copying it is cheap, so it's not really a big problem

Comment: @NeilKirk Sorry because my not so accurate English. I was not stating it is mandatory, just that it is being used for several implementations.

Comment: @NeilKirk, no, it's not mandatory. COW is forbidden, but implementers are allowed to use dynamic allocation even for strings of 1 byte if they choose.

Answer (score 1):

> To my understanding the value of a const string is copied if the variable is copied. Or am I wrong? I would say the reference counter can't be changed because it is const?

You are wrong. Typically the reference count will be `mutable`.

Whether your implementation has a reference-counted `std::string` or not should have no influence on whether you make variables const or not.